# GpioPinPwmOutput set pwm value with floating point

Tags: pwm, java, servo, pi4j

I have a `raspberry pi 4 B` and I want to control servo motor. I am using `NetBeans` IDE and `Java` programming language with `pi4j` library for raspberry. Also I have a servo motor that can rotate for 300 degree with `Pulse Width Range 500μS ~ 2500μS`. I have a class so I can control it by setting values in range 5-25 into `SetAngle` method. It wokrs fine, but I want to set floating point values to pwm, because pwm value and servo angle ratio is `1:15` so for every one on pwm I get 15 degress on servo motor. It is too big ration, that because I to be able to set floating point values to PWM. I read somewhere about `pigpio` library but didn't see any exmaples for it on `Java`. So the question itself - Could I somehow set floating vlaues to PWM using `pi4j` library or set PWM not in `ms` but in `μs`?

```java
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioController;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioFactory;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.GpioPinPwmOutput;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.Pin;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.PinState;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
/**
 *
 * @author abdra
 */
public class HCStandartServo 
{
    private GpioPinPwmOutput pwm;
    
    public HCStandartServo(Pin p)
    {
        GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
        pwm = gpio.provisionSoftPwmOutputPin(p);
        pwm.setPwmRange(100);
    }
    
    public void SetAngle(float angle)
    {
        pwm.setPwm((int)angle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just read the documentation for setPwm() ?  I don't understand what you want to know.

Comment: I have checked it and there is only ```setPwm(int value)```. And I don't know what should I do then

Comment: I would look at the implementation of SetPwm() and create a copy called mySetPwm().  I would change that to take a float value and make the needed changes within mySetPwm().  This has little to do with the Pi.

Comment: I still do not understand how to do this, when this method is inside ```GpioPinPwmOutput``` class and I can't see the code of the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of unsuccessful attempts, I still found a great solution to my problem. This solution is the repository: https://github.com/sarfata/pi-blaster. I just installed this on my `raspberry pi` and wrote a simple program to run my servo motors. At the very beginning of my program, the code is called that launches the `pi-blaster` via command line:

```java
String tmp;
String s = new String();
Process p;

try {
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo /home/pi/pi-blaster/pi-blaster");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println("[LINE]: " + tmp);
        s += tmp + "\n";
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println ("[EXIT]: " + p.exitValue());
    p.destroy();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

After this code, I can safely use pinouts of the board to control the servo motors.
Like this:

```java
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/dev/pi-blaster"), true))
{
    out.println("4=0.2");
}
```